# Easiest way to find index of last occurred selected character

Tags: jquery, arrays

I made code like below, but I'm not really happy about way it's done.
Maybe is an easiest way to find out e.g. index of all selected characters a string?
I know that I can use `indexOf()` (I know that I can search after an index) or `match()` but it's always returning index of first occurring element. I did try to `split()` string to array and use `inArray()` but still it's not that.

It's finding index of last occurring character what is my target.

```
    function returnLastUnderscorePosition(string, offset) {            
        if (!string || string.match('_') === null) {
            return 0;
        }

        var intPosition = string.match('_').index + 1,
                strStringToFind = string.slice(intPosition);

        if (strStringToFind.match('_')) {
            intPosition += returnLastUnderscorePosition(strStringToFind, intPosition);
        } else {
            return (offset) ? intPosition + offset : intPosition;
        }

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: `if (strStringToFind.match('_'))` is true, than you return nothing (`undefined`)...

Comment: [`String.prototype.lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lastIndexOf()` to get the position of the final occurrence of one string within another:

```
function returnLastUnderscorePosition(string, offset) {            
    if (!string || string.match('_') === null) 
        return 0;

    var intPosition = string.lastIndexOf('_');
    return (offset) ? intPosition + offset : intPosition;
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/1kv8dxq3/)

[Further reading on lastIndexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `.lastIndexOf()`?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf